# Newbie issue. How to check if input is empty in php, although the input could contain digit 0?

Tags: php, string, isset

I'm new to PHP and usually I use these lines to check if the input is empty:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['z']) || strlen(trim($_SESSION['z']) == 0))
 {
 echo "Unknown";
 }
```

But if the user types digit 0, a script recognises input as empty. How to change these lines to recognise 0 as a string?

Comment: The above code will *not* recognize "0" as empty and is a decent way to check for "truly empty" input. It does have a bug though, the `)` should go before the `== 0`.

Comment: Try typecasting it to an int and then use the identical operator. `(int)$_SESSION['z'] === 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution should have worked.  As commentator deceze pointed out, your second condition is mistyped it should be `strlen(trim($_SESSION['z'])) == 0`.

But alternate solution is to use strict equal check `===` and `!==`.

```
if(!isset($arr['z']) || trim($arr['z']) === '')
{
echo "Unknown";
}
```

This will work with if value is NULL or empty string, resulting 'Unknown'.  But any other value would not satisfy the condition, so value 0 or 0.0 should work.

But again, your initial solution is good. Just fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['z']) || strcmp(trim($_SESSION['z']), '') == 0)
{
  echo "Unknown";
}
```

The function `strcmp` returns 0, if two `string`s are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["z"])){$_SESSION['z']=$_POST["z"];}
if(!isset($_SESSION['z']) OR $_SESSION['z']==""){
    echo "Unknown";
}else{
    echo $_SESSION['z'];
}
?>
<form method="post"><input type="text" name="z"><input type="submit"></form>
```

This should work as you want